# How to prevent Deadlock when updating Swing components using swing timers and invokeLater?

Tags: java, swing, timer, deadlock, invokelater

Can deadlock happen for an arbitrary synchronised method which updates some Swing components if the threads which call to this method all use Swing Timer or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` . I think that it will not be necessary to call invokeLater() inside Swing Timer tasks.

So I will have Some Swing timers and some observers that update my components. Observers all call `invokeLater()` and Swing Timers call my arbitrary method `updateComponents()` directly.

If it can still cause Deadlock, will `invokeLater()` make me sure that no deadlock will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions triggered by the Swing Timer, as well as runnables submitted to `invokeLater`, are all executed sequentially on the Event Dispatch Thread, and as long as you don't involve `invokeAndWait`, no other thread is waiting for an action to complete. Therefore no deadlock can arise from this usage pattern alone. If you do encounter a deadlock, the cause will not be related to the EDT and its event processing.

You do not need `invokeLater` from within any event callback, which includes the one submitted to the Swing Timer, because they are already guaranteed to be called on the Event Dispatch Thread.